# How to find tags with only certain attributes - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How would I, using BeautifulSoup, search for tags containing ONLY the attributes I search for?

For example, I want to find all `<td valign="top">` tags.

The following code:
`raw_card_data = soup.fetch('td', {'valign':re.compile('top')})`

gets all of the data I want, but also grabs any `<td>` tag that has the attribute `valign:top`

I also tried:
`raw_card_data = soup.findAll(re.compile('<td valign="top">'))`
and this returns nothing (probably because of bad regex)

I was wondering if there was a way in BeautifulSoup to say "Find `<td>` tags whose only attribute is `valign:top`"

**UPDATE**
FOr example, if an HTML document contained the following `<td>` tags:

```
<td valign="top">.....</td><br />
<td width="580" valign="top">.......</td><br />
<td>.....</td><br />
```

I would want only the first `<td>` tag (`<td width="580" valign="top">`) to return

Answer (score 149, accepted):

As explained on the [BeautifulSoup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs%29)

You may use this :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
results = soup.findAll("td", {"valign" : "top"})
```

EDIT :

To return tags that have only the valign="top" attribute, you can check for the length of the tag `attrs` property :

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

html = '<td valign="top">.....</td>\
        <td width="580" valign="top">.......</td>\
        <td>.....</td>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
results = soup.findAll("td", {"valign" : "top"})

for result in results :
    if len(result.attrs) == 1 :
        print result
```

That returns :

```
<td valign="top">.....</td>
```

Comment: As per my comment to julio.alegria, This will find all `<tr>` tags with the attribute `valign="top"`, including ones with other attributes (`<td width="580" valign="top">` is also returned in this search) I'm looking for a method to find `<tr>` tags whose only attribute is `valign="top"`

Comment: So, you can check len(tag.attrs). If len(tag.attrs) > 1, ignore the tag (I have edited my post)

Answer (score 66):

You can use `lambda` functions in `findAll` as explained in [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#match-callable). So that in your case to search for `td` tag with only `valign = "top"` use following:

```
td_tag_list = soup.findAll(
                lambda tag:tag.name == "td" and
                len(tag.attrs) == 1 and
                tag["valign"] == "top")
```

Comment: best answer as it uses the full power of BS

Comment: Great answer because its gives you result in very optimized way.

Comment: Risks a `KeyError` if the tag isn't actually `valign`.

Answer (score 61):

if you want to only search with attribute name with any value

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup= BeautifulSoup(html.text,'lxml')
results = soup.findAll("td", {"valign" : re.compile(r".*")})
```

as per Steve Lorimer better to pass True instead of regex

```
results = soup.findAll("td", {"valign" : True})
```

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis after `r".*"`, resulting in this not compiling.

Comment: No need for a regular expression, just pass `True`: `results = soup.findAll("td", {"valign" : True})`

Answer (score 20):

The easiest way to do this is with the new CSS style `select` method:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
results = soup.select('td[valign="top"]')
```

Comment: What if I don't know the value beforehand, and just want to find tag containing the valign attribute?

Comment: @MasayoMusic You can do soup.select('td[valign]') to select all <td> having 'valign' attribute. You can also omit the tag name to select all elements with 'valign' attribute

Answer (score 6):

find using an attribute in any tag

```
<th class="team" data-sort="team">Team</th>    
soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "team"}) 

<th data-sort="team">Team</th>  
soup.find_all(attrs={"data-sort": "team"})
```

Answer (score 5):

Just pass it as an argument of `findAll`:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("""
... <html>
... <head><title>My Title!</title></head>
... <body><table>
... <tr><td>First!</td>
... <td valign="top">Second!</td></tr>
... </table></body><html>
... """)
>>>
>>> soup.findAll('td')
[<td>First!</td>, <td valign="top">Second!</td>]
>>>
>>> soup.findAll('td', valign='top')
[<td valign="top">Second!</td>]
```

Comment: What if there are tags like so: `<td width="580" valign="top">`? I don't want to grab those, just tags whose only attribute is `valign="top"`

Answer (score 4):

Adding a combination of Chris Redford's and Amr's answer, you can also search for an attribute name with any value with the select command:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
html = '<td valign="top">.....</td>\
    <td width="580" valign="top">.......</td>\
    <td>.....</td>'
soup = Soup(html, 'lxml')
results = soup.select('td[valign]')
```

Comment: I have tried the same way but this is not working, is there any workaround?

Comment: @PhaneendraCharyuluKanduri Sorry, there was a bad coding error in the code. Now copy and paste should work!

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to pull all tags where a particular attribute is present *at all*, you can use the same code as the accepted answer, but instead of specifying a value for the tag, just put True.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
results = soup.findAll("td", {"valign" : True})
```

This will return all td tags that have valign attributes. This is useful if your project involves pulling info from a tag like div that is used all over, but can handle very specific attributes that you might be looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the name of all the tags in different lines that have specific attribute , for example printing all the tags with **id** attribute irrespective of the value :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup ;
from bs4 import element ;
html = '!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Navigate Parse Tree</title></head>\
<body><h1>This is your Assignment</h1><a href = "https://www.google.com">This is a link that will take you to Google</a>\
<ul><li><p> This question is given to test your knowledge of <b>Web Scraping</b></p>\
<p>Web scraping is a term used to describe the use of a program or algorithm to extract and process large amounts of data from the web.</p></li>\
<li id = "li2">This is an li tag given to you for scraping</li>\
<li>This li tag gives you the various ways to get data from a website\
<ol><li class = "list_or">Using API of the website</li><li>Scrape data using BeautifulSoup</li><li>Scrape data using Selenium</li>\
<li>Scrape data using Scrapy</li></ol></li>\
<li class = "list_or"><a href="https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/">\
Clicking on this takes you to the documentation of BeautifulSoup</a>\
<a href="https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/" id="anchor">Clicking on this takes you to the documentation of Selenium</a>\
</li></ul></body></html>'

data = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser');
for i in data.descendants :
     if type(i) == element.Tag:
        if i.attrs != {} and 'id' in i.attrs:
           print(i.name)
```