# How to select tags by attribute value with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML fragment:

```
>>> a
<div class="headercolumn">
<h2>
<a class="results" data-name="result-name" href="/xxy> my text</a>
</h2>
```

I am trying to select header column only if attribute data-name="result-name"

I've tried:

```
>>> a.select('a["data-name="result-name""]')
```

This gives:

```
ValueError: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector:
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933863/how-to-find-tags-with-only-certain-attributes-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
html = """
<div class="headercolumn">
<h2>
<a class="results" data-name="result-name" href="/xxy> my text</a>
</h2>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for d in soup.findAll("div",{"class":"headercolumn"}):
    print d.a.get("data-name")
    print d.select("a.results")

result-name
[<a class="results" data-name="result-name" href="/xxy&gt; my text&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/h2&gt;"></a>]
```

Comment: Thanks Padraic, would you mind explaining what is being selected in "print d.a.get("data-name")" - Bill

Comment: `d.a` is `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`, you are accessing it like a dict, if `data-name` exists in the tag it will will print the value which is `"result-name"` in this case, you could use `d.a["data-name"]` but if you are iterating over different elements from using find_all and if `data-name` does not exist you will get a keyError, using get will allow to check if it exists and continue if it does not.

Answer (score 11):

You can simply do this :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
results = soup.findAll("a", {"data-name" : "result-name"})
```

Source : [How to find tags with only certain attributes - BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933863/how-to-find-tags-with-only-certain-attributes-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 3):

select classes or ids

```
soup.select('a.gamers') # select an `a` tag with the class gamers
soup.select('a#gamer') # select an `a` tag with the id gamer
```

select single attr:

```
soup.select('a[attr="value"]')
```

select multiple attr:

```
attr_dict = {
             'attr1': 'val1',
             'attr2': 'val2',
             'attr3': 'val3'
            }

soup.findAll('a', attr_dict)
```

you can use any CSS selector in `soup.select`