# How to find all elements with a custom html attribute regardless of html tag using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have two cases where i want to scrape html tags with custom html attributes
This is the example of the html.  How do you scrape all the elements with the custom attribute "limit".

```
<div class="names" limit="10">Bar</div> 
<div id="30" limit="20">Foo</div> 
<li limit="x">Baz</li>
```

The second case is similar but with all the same html tags

```
<div class="names" limit="10">Bar</div> 
<div class="names" limit="20">Bar</div> 
<div class="names" limit="30">Bar</div>
```

My question is different than [How to find tags with only certain attributes - BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933863/how-to-find-tags-with-only-certain-attributes-beautifulsoup) because the latter targets attribute values with a specific tag whereas my question finds attributes only regardless of tag or value

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find tags with only certain attributes - BeautifulSoup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933863/how-to-find-tags-with-only-certain-attributes-beautifulsoup)

Comment: has an attribute with a value ("valign" and "top"). almost the same but i need to scrape it using the attribute regardless of value.

Comment: **XPath** seems to be a good solution, can you use **lxml**?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
# First case:
soup.find_all(attrs={"limit":True})

# Second case:
soup.find_all("div", attrs={"limit":True})
```

Reference:

- http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kwargs
- http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all

---

If your attribute name doesn't collide with either Python keywords or `soup.find_all` named args, the syntax is simpler:

```
soup.find_all(id=True)
```

Comment: Even cooler: `soup.find_all(attrs={"limit":lambda x: x and x.isdigit() and 5 <int(x) < 15})`