# How to find an email address from the below elements?

Tags: python, regex

How to find an email address using regex and considering `mailto:` as a flag. I tried with an expression but it only parses a small portion.

```
import re
html_content='''
<p><a href="mailto:info@mohindraroto.com">info@mohindraroto.com</a></p>
'''
row = re.findall(r'mailto:(\w*.)',html_content)[0]
print(row)
```

It gives me:

```
info@
```

Any help to modify my existing expression or create a new one for the sake of finding email will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Here's a [nice little regex](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) that can find email-addresses.

Comment: [Don't use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), or email addresses either.

Comment: @timgeb, Thanks for the link to your nice little regex. I didn't see any `mailto:` flag used in that expression.

Comment: Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31416858/is-it-possible-to-find-all-elements-with-a-custom-html-attribute-in-beautiful-so) to find all instances of `mailto` and then do your magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `(?:.*mailto:)([^"]*)"` will work as well. it uses a non-capturing group to find the "mailto: and catptures the text after until the closing `"` which is not captured.

Comment: Yep, your expression works. +1 for this. Gonna accept it in a while. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For your example, I would suggest matching a pattern that starts with `mailto:` followed by any character but `double quotes`:-

```
row = re.findall(r'mailto:([^"]*)',html_content)
print(row)
```

Comment: Your expression is working as well in this very case. +1 for this.

Comment: @yoda nice to see your activity on SO too, like unix forums `+1`

Answer (score 0):

This will work based on your current example:

```
'mailto:(\w*.\w*.com)'
```

This works as long as it is a .com email address

I think the regex stops at the @ because it is a special character and not a word or something along those lines

Comment: `\w` is not a "word" it is short hand for `a-zA-Z0-9_`. This wouldn't work for an email such as `chris.me@gmail.com`, not `chris-me@gmail.com`. The `.` is loosely matching the `@`.