# In Python, how do I find elements that contain a specific attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm using Python 3.7.  I want to locate all the elements in my HTML page that have an attribute, "data-permalink", regardless of what its value is, even if the value is empty.  However, I'm confused about how to do this.  I'm using the bs4 package and tried the following

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
soup.findAll("data-permalink")
[]
soup.findAll("a")
[<a href=" ... </a>]
soup.findAll("a.data-permalink")
[]
```

The attribute is normally only found in anchor tags on my page, hence my unsuccessful, "a.data-permalink" attempt.  I would like to return the elements that contain the attribute.

Comment: This might be relevant to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31416858/how-to-find-all-elements-with-a-custom-html-attribute-with-beautiful-soup

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if there's any way to make their example more generic?  They have "soup.find_all("div", attrs={"limit":True})" and I was wondering if there is a way to substitute "True" for some kind of expression that means match anything.

Comment: True will match anything. If you prefer css-selectors: `soup.select('a[data-permalink]')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is invalid

```
soup.findAll("a.data-permalink")
```

it should be used for the method `.select()` but still it invalid because it mean select `<a>` with the class not the attribute.

to match everything use the `*` for `select()`

```
.select('*[data-permalink]')
```

or `True` if using `findAll()`

```
.findAll(True, attrs={'data-permalink' : True})
```

example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<a data-permalink="a">link</a>
<b>bold</b>
<i data-permalink="i">italic</i>'''

soup= BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
permalink  = soup.select('*[data-permalink]')
# or
# permalink  = soup.findAll(True, attrs={'data-permalink' : True})
print(permalink)
```

Results, the `<b>` element is skipped

```
[<a data-permalink="a">link</a>, <i data-permalink="i">italic</i>]
```