# How do I fetch value inside many divs from html?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I can´t make the BeautifulSoup parse the entire code from this website: https://www.bcb.gov.br/

The value I want is between `<app-root> ... <\app-root>`, but when I use the following code, what's inside the `app-root` tag is not parsed:

```
import urllib.request as urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = 'https://www.bcb.gov.br'

page = urllib2.urlopen(html)

soup = bs(page, 'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

The result is:

```
<!DOCTYPE doctype html>
<html lang="en"><head><meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/> 
<script>document.head.innerHTML += "<base href='" + window.location.protocol 
+ "//" + window.location.host +"/" + "'>"</script><meta charset="utf-8"/> 
<title>Banco Central do Brasil</title><meta content="width=device- 
width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/><link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" 
type="image/x-icon"/><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Cormorant+Garamond:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i| 
Ubuntu:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet"/><script 
src="assets/js/config.js"></script><link 
href="styles.ad070d90de458f2251ec.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head> 
<body><app-root></app-root><!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics 
--><script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA- 
65460906-3"></script><script>window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-65460906-3');</script><script 
src="inline.b9c96f03aa7f6b76c42d.bundle.js?v=5" type="text/javascript"> 
</script><script src="polyfills.a7b9da535b3a5a6fbe04.bundle.js?v=5" 
type="text/javascript"></script><script 
src="scripts.b27f0359c1c3f740a0de.bundle.js?v=5" type="text/javascript"> 
</script><script src="vendor.3d7ec463120170ac4b21.bundle.js?v=5" 
type="text/javascript"></script><script 
src="main.36b8710c7447c7df695a.bundle.js?v=5" type="text/javascript"> 
</script></body></html>
```

You can see the tags `<app-root></app-root>` before `...Global site tag...` without showing what's inside them. That's why I can't scrape the values I want.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Is it because that's a custom html element and your parser [does not recognise it](http://blog.thehumangeo.com/2015/07/09/no-soup-for-you-when-beautiful-soup-doesnt-like-your-xml/). My guess is there's a flag you can enable similar to [custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31416858/how-to-find-all-elements-with-a-custom-html-attribute-with-beautiful-soup)

Comment: How can I enable this custom attribute?

Comment: @Wkim this has nothing to do with the parser as you can see by just printing the `page` content - it's a client-side app  which needs javascript to be executed by the client to build the page content. You'll need a headless browser to get the effective content.

Comment: @lloyd this has absolutely nothing to do with the parser...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks man! How can I use this headless browser? Do I need selenium then?

Comment: @Wkim I'm sure you'll find quite some other questions (and answers) about scraping js-apps based websites with selenium or some other solution... This is not really anything new ;-)

Comment: Thanks Bruno! I solved it with selenium!

Answer (score 1):

You have to let the page render first before grabbing the the html.

You can do that by using wither [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or [Requests-HTML](https://html.python-requests.org/)

Here's an example with Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = 'https://www.bcb.gov.br'

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)

soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is empty as served by the server. Just see plain text of the page.

```
for line in page:
  print(line)
```