# How to get the contents inside of a div tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I was wondering what I need to put inside of the .find parameter when using beautifulsoup to get the contents of "the-target" shown below.

```
<div class="item" the-target="this text" another-target="not this text">
```

This is the .find beautifulsoup parameter I am talking about

> help = soup.find('div', 'What should I put here?').get_text()

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all elements with a custom html attribute with Beautiful Soup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31416858/how-to-find-all-elements-with-a-custom-html-attribute-with-beautiful-soup)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the `div` with class `item` and get the value of `the-target` key from the resulting tag object (which is a `dict`-like object):

```
soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'item'})['the-target']
```

If you want to find by the `the-target` attribute:

```
soup.find('div', attrs={'the-target': 'this text'})
```

And get the value of the attribute like before:

```
soup.find('div', attrs={'the-target': 'this text'})['the-target']
```

In two steps:

```
tag = soup.find('div', attrs={'the-target': 'this text'})
the_target = tag.get('the-target')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Just for learning purposes how would I get the "the-target" if it was like this. 
<div class="item" another-target="not this text" the-target="this text" > "

Comment: @ImNotAFanOfLife The same `soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'item'})['the-target']`. Changing attribute position in the tag does not change anything.

Comment: @ImNotAFanOfLife Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use css selector to find item.

```
soup.select_one('div.item')['the-target']
```

OR

```
soup.select_one('.item')['the-target']
```