# Scraping a table with no id with python/beautifulsoup, how can I use the literal html string?

Tags: python, html, html-table, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

There is no specific table id for the table I want to scrape, and the height/width levels of the table match other tables on the same page, but the literal html string is unique:

`<table border="10%" cellpadding="10%" cellspacing="10%" width="100%">`

So what is the formatting within "soup.find()" to find this literal string.

Comment: an example of what you mean would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the tables in the page using the `findAll('table')` method, then put the table objects in a string constructor to get their literal html code.
(The string constructor basically calls `__str__()` on the table object)

Example:

```
import bs4

page = """

<html>
    <head> </head>

    <body>
        <table border="10%" cellpadding="10%" cellspacing="10%" width="100%"">
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th> 
            <th>Age</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Altair</td>
            <td>Ibn La Ahad</td> 
            <td>939</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ezio </td>
            <td>Auditore</td> 
            <td>604</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>

"""

bs= bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

tables = bs.findAll('table') # Find all tables

# for each table
for table in tables:
    table_html_code= str(table)          #get html code of this table

    first_line = table_html_code.split('\n')[0] # get first line of the table's html code
    print(first_line)
```

Another thing you can try is to use the order of tables. If you want to access the fourth table in the page you can access the table like this:

```
beautifulsoup_obj.findAll('table')[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the documentation it looks like you can do the following with the find() method.  You can pass in a dictionary of html attributes.  It looks like [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933863/how-to-find-tags-with-only-certain-attributes-beautifulsoup) has a similar question/solution.

BeautilSoup.find(self, name=None, attrs={}, recursive=True, text=None, **kwargs)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<html>
<head>
</head>

 <body>
    <table border="10%" cellpadding="10%" cellspacing="10%" width="100%"></table>

    <table></table
</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find("table", {"border": "10%", "cellpadding": "10%", "cellspacing": "10%", "width": "100%"})

print(results)
```