# how to get specific part in python beautifulsoup without using loop

Tags: python

my code:

```
page = requests.get("http://www.freejobalert.com/upsc-recruitment/16960/#Engg-Services2019")
c = page.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
tables=soup.find_all("table",{"style":"width: 500px;"})
```

Html table:

```
<table style="width: 500px;" border="2">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>Union Public Service Commission (UPSC)</strong></span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ff00ff;"><strong>Advt No.01/2019</strong></span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #008000;"><strong><strong><strong>Engineering Services (Prelims) Exam 2019</strong></strong></strong></span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong><a href="http://www.freejobalert.com" target="_blank">WWW.FREEJOBALERT.COM</a></strong></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="2"><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>Application Fee</strong></span></p>
<ul>
<li style="text-align: left;"><span style="line-height: 19px;">For Female/SC/ST/ PH: <strong>NIL</strong></span></li>
<li style="text-align: left;"><span style="line-height: 19px;">For Others: <strong>Rs. 200/-</strong></span></li>
<li style="text-align: left;">Candidates can pay either by depositing the money in any Branch of SBI by cash or by using net banking facility of SBI.</li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="2"><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong><strong>Important Dates</strong></strong></span></p>
<ul>
<li style="text-align: left;">Starting Date to Apply Online: <strong>26-09-2018</strong></li>
<li style="text-align: left;"><span style="line-height: 19px;">Last Date to Apply Online: <strong>22-10-2018 till 06:00 PM</strong></span></li>
<li style="text-align: left;"><span style="line-height: 19px;">Date for Preliminary Exam:<strong> 06-01-2019</strong></span></li>
<li style="text-align: left;"><span style="line-height: 19px;">Last date for Fee Payment (Pay by cash):<strong> 21-10-2018 at 11.59 PM</strong></span></li>
<li style="text-align: left;"><span style="line-height: 19px;">Last date for Fee Payment (online):<strong> 22-10-201</strong></span><strong>8 till 06:00 PM</strong></li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am expecting:

```
[
    <td colspan="2">
    <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>Union Public Service Commission (UPSC)</strong></span></p>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ff00ff;"><strong>Advt No.01/2019</strong></span></p>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #008000;"><strong><strong><strong>Engineering Services (Prelims) Exam 2019</strong></strong></strong></span></p>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><strong><a href="http://www.freejobalert.com" target="_blank">WWW.FREEJOBALERT.COM</a></strong></p>
    </td>
]
```

how can i get these part of html using beautiful soup without using loop..
i want all  with colspan="2"

please have a look into this code..

Thanks....

Comment: Do you want `td` elements that have the `colspan="2"` attribute only? Or `td` elements with other attributes too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find tags with only certain attributes - BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933863/how-to-find-tags-with-only-certain-attributes-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What prevent you to directly find_all that element?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get("http://www.freejobalert.com/upsc-recruitment/"
"16960/#Engg-Services2019")
c = page.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
tables = soup.find_all("td", attrs={'colspan':'2'})
print(tables)
```