# Python BeautifulSoup get attribute values from any element containing an attribute

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

In beautifulSoup I can target all elements by tag, i.e:

```
BeautifulSoup().find_all('img')
```

or by src attribute as long as I also specify an attribute value, i.e:

```
BeautifulSoup().find_all(attrs={"src": "some.domain.com/file."})
```

How can I target all elements with an src attribute regardless of whatever that src attributes value is?

Comment: Could you provide an example of html?

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: This is practically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/8933863/11301900. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45365599/11301900.

Comment: @AMC No it's not. The question was clear. I am explaining that if the attributes value is known, I can target it. I am asking about how to target an attribute with an unknown value. None of the answers in the question you posted even use the attribute selector without a value. How is this a duplicate when the question is different and the answer is not there?

Comment: @PaulB _None of the answers in the question you posted even use the attribute selector without a value._ Isn't the answer I linked to doing exactly that?

Comment: @AMC The guy asks: 'I was wondering if there was a way in BeautifulSoup to say "Find <td> tags whose only attribute is valign:top"' In which case he has both the tag and the value. What you link to is not an answer to the question but an additional expansion.

Comment: @PaulB Yes, it's a useful/relevant answer, which is why I shared it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have **bs4 4.7.1** or above you can use the following css selector.

```
for item in soup.select('[src]'):
    print(item)
```

Comment: Wont' this target img elements with src attribute? As I mentioned in the description I want any element with an src attribute

Comment: I have removed it.can you try now and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
BeautifulSoup().find_all(attrs={"src": re.compile('*')})
```

Comment: Yep. This works but I prefer to avoid using regex if it can be avoided. 
Thank you.