# Solved: BeautifulSoup4 get_text() while scraping works on mac but returns empty string on raspbian

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a simple web-scraper that as of now works surprisingly well - on my macbook anyway. My intent is to move the script to my Raspberry Pi and run it automatically every day - but one line of code doesn't work properly. Normally I'm able to solve most of my problems by googling and reading here on Stack Overflow but now I'm stumped.

So I'm parsing the webpage for several type='application/ld+json' parts, then loading each as json for further processing. I'm skipping the first element as I know it's not important for my purposes.

```
data = soup.select("[type='application/ld+json']")

for j in data[1:]:

   temp = j.get_text()
   try:
       temp = json.loads(temp)
       <do stuff> 
   except Exception as err:
       print(err)
```

When I run the code on my mac, everything works well. However when I run the script om my Raspberry, get_text() returns en empty string which gives the error

```
 "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"
```

Example contents of j, before .get_text():

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "City",
  "address" : {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "City" : "Oslo"
   }
}
</script>
```

I have tried adding some print-functions for debugging, including checking if the variable j actually contains something and it does - everything look right, just as on my Mac. I've checked the object types and j is a BeautifulSoup-tag as it should, and temp is a string efter .get_text(). The only difference is that get_text() returns an empty string on my Raspberry while it returns the contents of "script"  when it's run on my Mac.

What am I missing or doing wrong? (besides naming my variable "temp")

EDIT: Ok, problem solved. Apparently I was using BS 4.8.2 on my Mac and 4.9.0 on the raspberry. And I found this in the documentation:

> As of Beautiful Soup version 4.9.0, when lxml or html.parser are in use, the contents of "script, "style", and "template" tags are not considered to be ‘text’, since those tags are not part of the human-visible content of the page.

I don't know if this is the correct way to do it, but once I changed this

`temp = j.get_text()`

to this

`temp = j.string`

everything worked as supposed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import json

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "City",
  "address" : {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "City" : "Oslo"
   }
}
</script>""", "html.parser")

json.loads(soup.find("script", attrs={"type": "application/ld+json"}).text)
```

[How to find tags with only certain attributes - BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933863/how-to-find-tags-with-only-certain-attributes-beautifulsoup)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it did not work either. It works on my mac but not on the raspberry. I'm getting the same error as with my code, "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)". No other bs4 error or anything else. .text or get_text() seem to return only a empty string and not the contents.