# python scrape input value from html

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hey I need to scrape an html for a specific shipping rate here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="methods" id="shipping-quotes" data-url="/en/webshipper/setshippingquote" data-shipping-fee="£ 12">
                                                                <li class="method-option method-option--shipping">
            <div class="method-option__header">
                <input
                    id="shippingrate-8"
                    name="shippingrate"
                    type="radio"
                    value="8"
                    class="method-option__input shipping-rate"
                    
                />
                <label for="shippingrate-8" class="method-option__label">
                    <span class="method-option__name">UPS Standard UK - Home Delivery (2-4 business days)</span>
                    <span class="method-option__fee">9 GBP</span>
                </label>
            </div>
                        </li>
                                                                <li class="method-option method-option--shipping">
            <div class="method-option__header">
                <input
                    id="shippingrate-9"
                    name="shippingrate"
                    type="radio"
                    value="9"
                    class="method-option__input shipping-rate"
                    
                />
                <label for="shippingrate-9" class="method-option__label">
                    <span class="method-option__name">UPS Standard UK - Pick-up Point (2-4 business days)</span>
                    <span class="method-option__fee">6 GBP</span>
                </label>
            </div>
                        </li>
                                                                <li class="method-option method-option--shipping">
            <div class="method-option__header">
                <input
                    id="shippingrate-15"
                    name="shippingrate"
                    type="radio"
                    value="15"
                    class="method-option__input shipping-rate"
                    
                />
                <label for="shippingrate-15" class="method-option__label">
                    <span class="method-option__name">UPS Express UK - Home Delivery (2-4 business days)</span>
                    <span class="method-option__fee">15 GBP</span>
                </label>
            </div>
                        </li>
                                                                <li class="method-option method-option--shipping">
            <div class="method-option__header">
                <input
                    id="shippingrate-29"
                    name="shippingrate"
                    type="radio"
                    value="29"
                    class="method-option__input shipping-rate"
                    checked
                />
                <label for="shippingrate-29" class="method-option__label">
                    <span class="method-option__name">UPS Express UK - Pick-up Point (1-3 business days)</span>
                    <span class="method-option__fee">12 GBP</span>
                </label>
            </div>
                                
<div class="drop-points" id="drop-points">
    <p class="drop-point drop-point--no-result">
        No pickup points found near your chosen location
    </p>
</div>
                        </li>
        </ul>
```

Specifically the home delivery option so in the HTML below I would need to get the value= 9 value so I would like to get the value of 9. How could I get the specific value for the home delivery option using bs4?

If I am unclear i mean the value option
within this

```
<input
                    id="shippingrate-9"
                    name="shippingrate"
                    type="radio"
                    value="9"
                    class="method-option__input shipping-rate"

                />
```

For the home delivery 2-4 days option.

Comment: As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933863/how-to-find-tags-with-only-certain-attributes-beautifulsoup), you should be able to use something like `soup.find('input', {'name': 'shippingrate'}).attrs['value']`.

Comment: that gets the first value, how do I get the shipping rate value for the "home delivery" option?

Comment: Use `soup.find_all` and a loop. You need to read the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#beautiful-soup-documentation) as you seem to lack the basics and are trying to run before you can walk.

Comment: i understand find all but how can I search for the value in between a class within a label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the input value of shipping method (let's say `UPS Standard UK - Pick-up Point (2-4 business days)` in your case), you can first find all `div`s then pick the one with this method. So something like this will do the job:

```
data = soup.find('ul', attrs={'id': 'shipping-quotes'}).find_all('div', class_='method-option__header')

values = [each.input['value'] for each in data if each.find('span', class_='method-option__name').text == 'UPS Standard UK - Pick-up Point (2-4 business days)']
```

`values` will be:

```
['9']
```

Comment: hey how could i get the value of 9 not the shipping method for the value of 9. SO what I mean is I want to get the value number for the home delivery option

Comment: @MovieClips edited, check if this is what you want

Answer (score 1):

You've not shown any effort at all but since I needed a break...

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''\
<ul class="methods" id="shipping-quotes" data-url="/en/webshipper/setshippingquote" data-shipping-fee="£ 12">
  <li class="method-option method-option--shipping">
    <div class="method-option__header">
    <input id="shippingrate-8" name="shippingrate" type="radio" value="8" class="method-option__input shipping-rate" /> 
    <label for="shippingrate-8" class="method-option__label">
    <span class="method-option__name">UPS Standard UK - Home Delivery (2-4 business days)</span> 
    <span class="method-option__fee">9 GBP</span></label></div>
  </li>
  <li class="method-option method-option--shipping">
    <div class="method-option__header">
    <input id="shippingrate-9" name="shippingrate" type="radio" value="9" class="method-option__input shipping-rate" /> 
    <label for="shippingrate-9" class="method-option__label">
    <span class="method-option__name">UPS Standard UK - Pick-up Point (2-4 business days)</span> 
    <span class="method-option__fee">6 GBP</span></label></div>
  </li>
  <li class="method-option method-option--shipping">
    <div class="method-option__header">
    <input id="shippingrate-15" name="shippingrate" type="radio" value="15" class="method-option__input shipping-rate" /> 
    <label for="shippingrate-15" class="method-option__label">
    <span class="method-option__name">UPS Express UK - Home Delivery (2-4 business days)</span> 
    <span class="method-option__fee">15 GBP</span></label></div>
  </li>
  <li class="method-option method-option--shipping">
    <div class="method-option__header">
    <input id="shippingrate-29" name="shippingrate" type="radio" value="29" class="method-option__input shipping-rate"
    checked="checked" /> 
    <label for="shippingrate-29" class="method-option__label">
    <span class="method-option__name">UPS Express UK - Pick-up Point (1-3 business days)</span> 
    <span class="method-option__fee">12 GBP</span></label></div>
    <div class="drop-points" id="drop-points">
      <p class="drop-point drop-point--no-result">No pickup points found near your chosen location</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
for d in soup.select('div.method-option__header'):
    rate = d.find('input', {'name': 'shippingrate'}).attrs['value']
    name = d.find('span', {'class': 'method-option__name'}).text
    fee = d.find('span', {'class': 'method-option__fee'}).text
    print(f"{rate}\t{name}\t{fee}")
```