# How do I reference attribute when using python/beautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

Look at the code snippet below.  I have figured out that the "_ngcontent..." is angular, but how do I reference this `div` using that attribute?

Typically, I would tell `soup` to give me the `div` with the class/id/name, etc, but I don't know how to reference this `_ng####`?

```
<div _ngcontent-bpi-q1346="" class="grid-row ng-star-inserted">
```

Comment: I think the third answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933863/how-to-find-tags-with-only-certain-attributes-beautifulsoup will do it

Comment: Ahhh, I see, let me test it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if `_ngcontent-bpi-q1346` exists in the tags attribute using the [`.attrs`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) method.

```
for tag in soup.find_all(
    lambda tag: tag.name == "div" and "_ngcontent-bpi-q1346" in tag.attrs
):
    print(tag)
```

Or: pass a Dictionary with the attribute name to the `attrs=` argument (second to the last example in the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments)).

```
# Using `True` as the value since `_ngcontent-bpi-q1346` doesn't have a value
for tag in soup.find_all("div", attrs={"_ngcontent-bpi-q1346": True}):
    print(tag)
```

Comment: Hi MendelG - I used the second option and it worked like a charm.  Thank so much!