# Use Python to scrape a table from a website

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, html-table

I am here to ask for help on how to write a program to capture the value 10,599 from below site.

https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/stat_20221001.html

The element that contains the value that I want to capture is as follows.

`<td class="hRight" headers="Total_Departure" data-label="Total">10,599</td>`

Thanks for the help in advance!

I am fairly new to python and recently I have just been enlightened that I can use selenium or bs4 to scrape a website onto a table.  After researching many websites and watching countless youtube videos, my effort is still in vain.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this locator:

```
.//td[@headers='Control_Point' and text()='Total']//parent::tr//td[@headers='Total_Departure']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Beautifulsoup to [find tags with certain attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933863/how-to-find-tags-with-only-certain-attributes-beautifulsoup)

**Code**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/stat_20221001.html'
req = requests.get(url)

if req.ok:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html5lib')  # or lxml by default instead of html5lib
    # Many cells have desired attributes.  We take the last one.
    table_cell = soup.find_all('td', attrs={"class":"hRight", 
                                            "data-label":"Total",
                                            "headers":"Total_Departure"}
                               )[-1]  # -1 for last cell in list found
    
    print(table_cell.text)     # print table cell text
else:
    raise Exception("Sorry, error with url request")
```

**Output**

```
10,599
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This works splendidly!